# How to switch two letters in a word which is in a tuple using list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples with words that are already split :

```
split_l = [('', 'eta'), ('e', 'ta'), ('et', 'a'), ('eta', '')]
```

I want to split the position of the word `eta` which is on the right in the first tuple into 2 new words.

Code:

```
switch_l = [L + R[1] + R[2:] for L,R in split_l if len(R) >= 2]
```

Expected result:

```
switch_l = ['tea', 'eat']
```

Current result:

```
switch_l = ['ta', 'ea']
```

For example, taking `e` and swapping it with `t` will produce `tea`. Then swapping `t` with `a` to produce `eat`. Swapping should be done if the rightmost element of the tuple has a len() > 2.

Comment: What's the logic here?

Comment: For example, taking ```e``` and swapping it with ```t``` will produce ```tea```. Then swapping ```t``` with ```a``` to produce ```eat```. Swapping should be done if the rightmost element of the tuple has a ```len() > 2```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the initial logic is correct for your list comprehension. You want to look for tuple pairs that contain two strings of length of at least 1 and swap the last and first characters of the first and second strings respectively:

```
switch_L = [L[:-1] + R[0] + L[-1] + R[1:] for L,R in split_l if len(L) > 0 and len(R) > 0]
```